# How do I `puts` an element at a certain position of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How do I `puts` an element at a certain position of an array?

```
count = array.count
for n in 1..count.step(3) do
  puts array[n]
end
```

Comment: You mean to get what is indexed at that point of the array?  Pretty much as you have `array[n]`

Comment: get us some input and output

Comment: the "array[n]" didn't work

Comment: the second code below works perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate your array better with ruby methods like this:

```
array.each do |array_item|
  puts array_item
end
```

but for your need try this one

```
count=array.count
(1..count).step(3) do |counter|
    puts array[counter]
end
```

Comment: `array_item` not `array__item`